# Mac Bootcamp - Showing hard drive selection on boot

Tags: macos, mac, boot, boot-camp

Can i make my computer boot straight into the hard drive selection screen? My current method is always pressing the option key on start up.

This is the screen that i'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done with native tools, but you can use [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8779/always-prompt-for-boot-device-on-startup) (disclaimer: I don't use it, I just hold the option button).

Alternatively, you can check [bootchamp](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/28468/bootchamp) out, it makes rebooting to windows easier.

Comment: i should have followed the disclaimer, now i have boot problems :(